# Java Fx custom image as scatter chart data point

Tags: java, javafx

I have an input stream representing which is basically an image. I want a series to be represented by this image. For now I have something like that:

```
public void update(ComputationState finalState) {
    getData().clear();
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    for (PizzaDeliverer entry : finalState.getPizzas()) {
        XYChart.Data<Number, Number> dataEntry = new XYChart.Data<>(entry.getCurrentPosition().getX(), entry.getCurrentPosition().getY());
        series.getData().add(dataEntry);
    }
    series.setName(null);
    getData().add(series);
}
```

I extended the `ScatterChart<Number,Number>` class to fit my needs (it has to be updated).

I want the data entries to be represented by lets say pizza images. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void update(ComputationState finalState) {
    getData().clear();
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();

    final int imgWidth = 20 ; 
    final int imgHeight = 20 ; 
    final Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("pizza.png"), imgWidth, imgHeight, true, true, true);

    for (PizzaDeliverer entry : finalState.getPizzas()) {
        XYChart.Data<Number, Number> dataEntry = new XYChart.Data<>(entry.getCurrentPosition().getX(), entry.getCurrentPosition().getY());
        dataEntry.setNode(new ImageView(img));
        series.getData().add(dataEntry);
    }
    series.setName(null);
    getData().add(series);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about images, but I'm assuming it can be done using CSS. Try reading more [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm)
Specifically, try using :

```
.chart-symbol {
    -fx-image: url("image.png");
}
```